# Error opening photos stored in zip file in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-2.2

I'm going to create a zip file from some of the image files stored on my server.
I've used the following function to do this:

```
def create_zip_file(user, examination):
    from lms.models import StudentAnswer
    f = BytesIO()
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'w')
    this_student_answer = StudentAnswer.objects.filter(student_id=user.id, exam=examination)

    for answer in this_student_answer:
        if answer.answer_file:
            answer_file_full_path = answer.answer_file.path
            fdir, fname = os.path.split(answer_file_full_path)
            zip.writestr(fname, answer_file_full_path)
    zip.close()  # Close
    zip_file_name = "student-answers_"+ str(examination.id)+"_" + str(user.id) + "_" + date=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M") + '.zip'
    response = HttpResponse(f.getvalue(), content_type="application/x-zip-compressed")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % zip_file_name
    return response
```

Everything is fine and all photos are made in zip file but there is only one problem.
 **The problem is that the photos won't open and this error will appear in Windows:**

> `Its look like we don't support this file format.`

What is wrong with my codes?

Comment: code seems OK but maybe your system doesn't have decompressor for zip files.

Comment: read [Note](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZIP_LZMA) in documentation about different formats used in zipfile.

Comment: So what should I do now? @furas

Comment: I don't uses `Windows` many year` but when I was using Windows then I always  installed free [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) or [PeaZip](https://www.peazip.org/), eventually [WinZIp](https://www.winzip.com/win/en/) but it is not free.

Comment: I did test `7-zip`  and `PeaZip` but the result was as same as error. Do you sure that there is not any wrong when I create new `jpg` inside zip file? @furas

Comment: do you have problem to uncompress zip file or open jpg file after uncompressing? If you have to problem to open jpg file then open it in any text editor to see what you have inside this file.

Comment: I can't run code but maybe you should use [write(filename)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) because `writestr()` doesn't open file and doesn't copy from file to `ByteIO` but it puts only path as string in `ByteIO`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append data from file you have to use

[write(filename)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write)

Using `writestr(filename)` you add only string from variable `filename` but not from file.